# Lower bound : resource required by an algorithm for some class of input size n

Tags: algorithm, code-analysis

I've been asked to find the lower bound of the following :

T(n)= 23n^3-n^2-n.

So here is how i proceeded and i don't know whether I'm tackling it the proper way:

T(n)>=c(23n^2-n^2) for all n greater than n>=n0

23n^3-n^2-n >=(22n^2) for all n>=2.

T(n)>=c|n^2| for all n>=2
c=22 n0=22.
T(n) is in Big Omega n^2

HELP PLEASE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `n^3 >= n^2` for `n >= 1`. So, `-n^3 <= -n^2` for `n >= 1`.

Note that `n^3 >= n` for `n >= 1`. So, `-n^2 <= -n` for `n >= 1`.

So

```
23n^3 - n^2 - n >= 23n^3 - n^3 - n^3 = 21n^3.
```

Thus, `21n^3` is a decent lower bound.

Intuitively this makes sense as `23n^3 - n^2 - n` is clearly cubic in nature, and thus should have lower bound and upper bound of `cn^3` for some `c` (different `c` for the lower bound from the `c` for the upper bound).

Comment: THANK YOU.
So now the function T(n) will be bounded as follows: